# Animated.event does not change state

Tags: react-native, scroll, react-animated

In react-native I am using the Swiper module found [here](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper):

```
<Swiper
      bounces={true}
      loop={false}
      showsPagination={false}
      onScroll={this.handleScroll}
      scrollEventThrottle={1}
    >...
```

Then outside the render method, I defined handleScroll like this:

```
handleScroll = Animated.event(
  [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: this.state.left } } }],
  {
    listener: event => {
      console.log(this.state.left);
    }
  });
```

When performing the scroll on Swiper and looking on the output nothing changes.

I am aware to put the Animated.event directly into onScroll and it works like this, but I am very curious why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Animated.event() returns a function handler you need to call that function.
Try this.

```
handleScroll = (event) => Animated.event(
  [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: this.state.left } } }],
  {
    listener: event => {
      console.log(this.state.left);
    }
  })(event);
```